# Probability in geometry: finding the probability of selecting a $5$-tuple such that a pentagon can be formed from its sides

Tags: probability, geometry, algebraic-geometry, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Consider all tuples of  $5$ real numbers each less than $5$.
Find the probability of selecting a tuple such that a pentagon could be formed from its sides.

My attempt : 
I tried to visualize the problem for a triangle and could come up with a solution with graphs but I don't know how to approach this for the above one .

Part 2 : 
Solve the above problem if the sum of the elements of the tuple is 5.

Comment: On the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683320/breaking-up-a-stick-into-different-pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[5] = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $X_i \sim \mathcal{U}([0,5)), i \in [5]$ be five iid random variables uniformly sampled over $[0,5)$. Let $Y_1 \ge Y_2, \cdots, Y_5$ be any reordering of them such that $Y_1$ is the largest number.

In order for $X_1,\ldots, X_5$ to form a pentagon, the necessary and sufficient condition is $$X_i < \sum\limits_{j=1,\ne i}^5 X_i\quad\text{ for }i \in [5]\quad\iff\quad
Y_1 < Y_2 + Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5\tag{*1}$$

Aside from events of probability zero, $Y_1 \in (0,5)$. When $Y_1 > 0$, define
$$Z_2 = \frac{Y_2}{Y_1},\quad Z_3 = \frac{Y_3}{Y_1},\quad Z_4 = \frac{Y_4}{Y_1}, \quad Z_5 = \frac{Y_5}{Y_1}$$
Under the assumption $Y_1 > 0$, it is easy to see $Z_2,\ldots,Z_5 \sim \mathcal{U}([0,1])$. As a result, the probability we seek equals to

$$
\verb/Pr/[ 1 < Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4 + Z_5]
= 1 - \underbrace{\verb/Pr/[Z_2 + Z_3 + Z_4 + Z_5 \le 1 ]}_{\text{ volume of a right-angled 4-simplex of sides 1}}
= 1 - \frac{1}{4!} = \frac{23}{24}$$

**Update**

For part 2, let $X = \sum_{i=1}^5 X_i$. Under the constraint $X = 5$, the condition on LHS of $(*1)$ becomes
$$X_i < X - X_i,\;\forall i \in [5]\quad\iff\quad X_i < \frac{5}{2},\; \forall i \in [5]$$

Notice up to events of probability zero, the events $X_i \ge \frac{5}{2}$ for different $i$ are disjoint.
This means the conditional probability for forming a pentagon can be evaluated as

$$\begin{align}\verb/Pr/\left[
\bigcap_{i=1}^5 \left( X_i < \frac{5}{2} \right) : X = 5 
\right]
&= 1 - \verb/Pr/\left[
\bigcup_{i=1}^5 \left(X_i \ge \frac{5}{2}\right) : X = 5 \right]\\
&= 1 - \sum_{i=1}^5 \verb/Pr/\left[ X_i \ge \frac{5}{2} : X = 5\right]\\
&= 1 - 5 \verb/Pr/\left[ X_1 \ge \frac{5}{2} : X = 5 \right]
\end{align}
$$
Geometrically, the region determined by the relations
$\frac{5}{2} \le X_1, 0 \le X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5$ and $X = 5$
is a 4-simplex whose sides is one half of the 4-simplex determined
by the relations $0 \le X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5$ and $X = 5$.
This implies
$$\verb/Pr/\left[ X_1 \ge \frac{5}{2} : X = 5 \right] = \frac{1}{2^4}$$
and as a result,

$$\verb/Pr/\left[
\bigcap_{i=1}^5 \left( X_i < \frac{5}{2} \right) : X = 5 
\right] = 1 - \frac{5}{16} = \frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: So each element smaller than 5 makes no difference ?

Comment: @ApoorvJain yes, the upper bound $5$ makes no difference. As long as the $5$ numbers are sampled over same range $[0,b)$ (or $[0,b]$), you get the same answer.

Comment: Thanks got it . There's a second part too which I have I just added . Could you explain it too ?

Comment: On the second part, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683320/breaking-up-a-stick-into-different-pieces.

Comment: @joriki the probability distribution of the sides will be different, I fear that will not give the correct number of this.

Comment: @achillehui: No. Contrary to appearances, the intervals you get from uniformly choosing $n$ points on an interval all have the same distribution. You can see this by instead choosing $n+1$ points on the circle, then unifomly randomly choosing one of them to be the place where you break the circle into the interval. The remaining points are uniformly distributed, and the circle construction shows that the intervals between them are all equivalent. See also Graham Kemp's answer to the linked question. (Also, it does yield the same result as you got ;-)

Comment: @joriki - hmm... if that is the case, then it is sort of unexpected. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, it is unexpected -- that's why I try using it in answers wherever I can, to make it more well-known :-)

Comment: I have no prior experience of a simplex so could you give a simple introduction of it in regard to this question .

Comment: @ApoorvJain a 2-simplex is a triangle, a 3-simplex is a tetrahedron. It will be hard to visual what a 4-simplex is directly. However, think about the problem of picking 3 random numbers $X_1, X_2, X_3$ from $[0,1]$. When $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 1$, the geometric shape will be an equilateral triangle with vertices at $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ and side $\sqrt{2}$. The points on it that satisfies $X_1 \ge \frac12$ will be another equilateral triangles with vertices $(1,0,0),(1/2,1/2,0), (1/2,0,1/2)$ and side $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Its area will be $\frac14$ of the larger triangle.

Answer (score 0):

**ad. 1**

**Hint 1**

The pentagon can be formed, if each side is smaller than the sum of the rest, ie:

$$a_k < a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5 - a_k$$
for $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

This leads us to the inequality
$$a_k < \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5}{2}$$

**Hint 2**

Assume, that the numbers are arranged in growing order, ie:
$$0<a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4\leq a_5\leq 5$$
Now we have to check the situations, where 
$$a_5<a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$$
Note, that if $a_1>\frac{5}{4}$, then $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4>4a_1>5\geq a_5$. Of course $p_1=P\left(a_5<\frac{5}{4}\right)=\frac{3}{4}$

If not (ie. $a_1\leq \frac{5}{4}$), then let's take $a_2 > \frac{5-a_1}{3}$ (and $a_2\geq a_1$) with probability $p_2 = \frac{10+a_1}{3(5-a_1)}$ - our condition is satisfied.

If not ($a_2 \leq \frac{5-a_1}{3})$, let's take $a_3>\frac{5-a_1-a_2}{2}$ (and $a_3\geq a_2$) with probability $p_3 = \frac{5+a_1+a_2}{2(5-a_2)}$ - we can create the pentagon.

If not, let's take $a_4 > 5-a_1-a_2-a_3$ (and $a_4\geq a_3$) with probability $p_4 = \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{5-a_3}$ - again our condition is satisfied.

If not (ie. $5 > a_+a_2+a_3+a_4$) selection of $a_5$ will decide, if the pentagon can be constructed. Of course in that situation we can construct pentagon only if $a_5 <  a_+a_2+a_3+a_4$ (where $a_5 \geq a_4$), so probability is $p_5=\frac{ a_+a_2+a_3}{5-a_4}$

If not, the pentagon can't be constructed.

Finally the probability can be computed by calculating the following integral:

$$P=p_1+q_1\left(\int\limits_0^\frac{5}{4}p_2+q_2\left(\int\limits_{a_1}^\frac{5-a_1}{3}p_3+q_3\left(\int\limits_{a_2}^\frac{5-a_1-a_2}{2}p_4+q_4\left(\int\limits_{a_3}^{5-a_1-a_2-a_3} p_5 da_4\right)da_3\right)da_2\right)da_1\right)$$
where $q_i=1-p_i$ are the probabilities of "if not's"

**ad 2**
Arrange the numbers in increasing order, ie:
$$0<a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4\leq a_5$$
We have:
$$a_1\in \left(0, \frac{5}{5}\right)$$
$$a_2\in \left(a_1, \frac{5-a_1}{4}\right)$$
$$a_3\in \left(a_2, \frac{5-a_1-a_2}{3}\right)$$
$$a_4\in \left(a_3, \frac{5-a_1-a_2-a_3}{2}\right)$$
$$a_5=5-a_1-a_2-a_3-a_4$$
Applying the following inequality to the biggest number
$$a_k < \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5}{2}$$
we obtain
$$\frac{5}{2}<a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$$
So we have:
$a_1 > \frac{\frac{5}{2}}{4}$ with probability $p_1=\frac{1-\frac{5}{8}}{1}=\frac{3}{8}$

If not then $a_2 > \frac{\frac{5}{2}-a_1}{3}$ with probability $p_2=\frac{\frac{5-a_1}{4}-\frac{\frac{5}{2}-a_1}{3}}{\frac{5-a_1}{4}-a_1}$

and so on...

Comment: I noted that but I don't know how to proceed from there .

Comment: @ApoorvJain I've edited my answer. Can you calculate from here?